# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function in React-Redux using React Final Form

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a store that handles login information. When I dispatch with the action, in the console it shows me an error.

### Error

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at onSubmit (Login.js:66)
    at Object.submit (final-form.es.js:1382)
    at handleSubmit (react-final-form.es.js:265)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4070)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:8243)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:8275)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:8288)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:8299)
    at react-dom.development.js:8508
    at batchedEventUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22396)
    at batchedEventUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3745)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:8507)
    at attemptToDispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:6005)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:5924)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22413)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3756)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5889)
```

Here is the code of:

### Store

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import loginReducer from "./slices/loginSlicer"


const store = configureStore({
reducer: {
    login: loginReducer
}
})

export default store;
```

And this is my:

### LoginSlicer

```
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

const initialState = {
    isLoading: false,
    isAuth:false,
    error:''
};

const loginSlice = createSlice({
    name:'login',
    initialState,
    reducer:{
        loginPending:(state) =>{
            state.isLoading = true;
        },
        loginSuccess:(state) =>{
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.isAuth  = true;
            state.error= " ";
        },
        loginFailed:(state,{payload}) =>{
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.error = payload;
        }
    }
});

const {reducer,actions} = loginSlice;

export const {loginPending,loginSuccess,loginFailed} = actions;

export default reducer;
```

### Any here is my Login.js

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import { Form } from "react-final-form";
import { TextField, showErrorOnBlur } from "mui-rff";
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux"

import {loginPending,loginSuccess,loginFailed} from "../slices/loginSlicer"

export default function Login({history}) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

const onSubmit = async (values) => {
    
      try {
        dispatch(loginPending());
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
}
```

Please help me with this, I'm new and having this problem. I tried multiple things, but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed node_modules and reinstaled all the dependencies again. Restarted, the server, and everything works fine.